# European vehicle info based on licence plate

Tags: europe, cars

I'd like to be able to create a service such as regcheck.org.uk (getting vehicle info from licence plates), however, I'm unable to find any clue as to where their data comes from. Any chance of getting such data? For Europe, specifically.

Comment: The UK Data on RegCheck.org.uk comes from the DVLA (Driver and Vehicle Licensing Agency)